# Simon Asks (Comparing Character in Two Strings) Kill an Infinite loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

The rule of the game Simon Says compares the individual character of the user input character sequence with each corresponding character sequence in Simon says. (assuming both sequences have the same length). Whenever the user has the same character at the same position as "Simon Says", the user increments their score by one.

I have set up the for and while loop that compares both sequences of character individually from i=0, however, I have some issue in killing the loop.

Any comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Here's what I have:

```
public class SimonSays {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

  String simonPattern;
  String userPattern;
  int userScore;
  int i;

  userScore = 0;
  simonPattern = scnr.next();
  userPattern  = scnr.next();


 for (i=0; i<=simonPattern.length();i++) {
    while(userPattern.charAt(i) == simonPattern.charAt(i)){
          userScore += userScore; 
          continue;
     }
     while(userPattern.charAt(i)!=simonPattern.charAt(i)){
          break;
    }
 }

  System.out.println("userScore: " + userScore);

  return;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `continue` and `break` in loop scope its **refer to the nearest loop** ([as you can see here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-continue)) - so when you use them in the `while` loop they refer to it.

This what cause the infinity loop:

```
while(userPattern.charAt(i) == simonPattern.charAt(i)){
          userScore += userScore; 
          continue; // this cause your infinity loop
}
```

The `continue` is execute on the `while` loop and the condition neer changes therefor - infinity loop.

In order to fix your issue, consider using the following code:

```
int userScore = 0;
for (; userScore < simonPattern.length(); userScore++) {
    if (userPattern.charAt(userScore) != simonPattern.charAt(userScore))
          break; 
 }
 //Value of userScore here is the number of times the if statement return false -> which mean mumber of same chars
```

As the `userScore` is the number of char we already check in the pattern.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. For line of code "userScore=userScore +i", should that be also included in the for loop or under the if statement? Or should it be under an else statement in the for loop?

Comment: @user10733654 It should be after the loop. Notice that the loop counter is also the actual score of the user as its count the number of char who are the same. I updated the answer. I am not sure, in simon says, if we found miss-match between simon pattern and the user we stop, right?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user10733654 if this answer helped you please mark it as accepted (the "v" mark at the left of the post) so other may use it also